# ElasticSearch query to find values greater than a certain length in an array field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

ElasticSearch 6.4.2.

We have documents with a field called `customCategories` which is an array field of many 5-character codes.

Today we discovered by accident that several documents inadvertently have that field without any commas, and the 5-character codes were all mashed together as one long string.

So I need to find all documents that have this issue.  So how do I run a query to return any documents where `customCategories` has any value in it that's longer than 5 characters?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "for(int i=0; i < doc['customCategories'].length; i++) {  if ( doc['customCategories'][i].length() > 5 ) { return true; }  }  return false;",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```